# Changing content on the same html file/page

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to explain my question, so I could not find anything by searching,but i will do my best to explain it.

I'm just starting to learn html/css and i am working on my first project, and i am curious how do I change content by clicking on navigation bar on the same html page.

here are my image examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is generally done using Javascript and AJAX.

Comment: If your content is not loaded dynamically AJAX is no of use. JavaScript is what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery solution...here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/zfu9y/)**</kbd>

To be able to use this you must include jQuery in the `<head>` section of your HTML document. e.g.

```
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

---

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li data-rel="1" class="active">Section 1</li>
      <li data-rel="2">Section 2</li>
      <li data-rel="3">Section 3</li>
      <li data-rel="4">Section 4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h4>Section 1</h4>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h4>Section 2</h4>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h4>Section 3</h4>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h4>Section 4</h4>
    </article>
  </section>

</div>
```

---

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  padding: 10px;
}
section {
  background: #7f7f7f;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  width: 740px;
  min-height: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #000;
}
section:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  background: #c3c3c3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid #000;
}
.active {
  background: #7f7f7f;
}
```

---

Put this script just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $('nav li').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
      $('section:nth-of-type('+$(this).data('rel')+')').stop().fadeIn(400, 'linear').siblings('section').stop().fadeOut(400, 'linear'); 
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**If you wanna use AJAX for getting content**

Of course first include jQuery library in your document like in previous example

```
 <head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
```

then

1. Create folder `includes` in your root folder then in `includes` folder create folder named `ext-content` then in folder `ext-content` create couple of HTML documents named e.g `content1.html`, `content2.html` ... with different content you wish to show of course without doctype and other stuff from index page just simple content.
   example of content page 
    `<div>Content</div>`
2. Change previously created navigation into this

   ```
   <nav>
     <ul>
       <li data-content="content1" class="active">Section 1</li>
       <li data-content="content2">Section 2</li>
       <li data-content="content3">Section 3</li>
       <li data-content="content4">Section 4</li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
   ```
3. Leave only one section and in that section create div with class `ext-content` like below

   ```
   <section>
     <article>
       <div class="ext-content">

       </div>
     </article>
   </section>
   ```
4. Use this script instead of one in the previous example

   ```
   $('nav li').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'includes/ext-content/'+$(this).data('content')+'.html',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(response) {
         $('.ext-content').html(response);
       }
     });
   });
   ```

***Note:** You don't need to use sections, articles e.t.c. you could use divs, spans...

Comment: umm i don't know, it is not working
here is my html file: [index.html](http://pastebin.com/wVtB8fbE)
css: [style.css](http://pastebin.com/vsap8Dr)
i get this: [pic](http://puu.sh/7Y1PO.png)
but none of the buttons are working

Comment: basically what i want is to make a those buttons containing different image galleries

Comment: @Jockey sorry I started with one approach and moved on to another...anyway it should be `data-rel="1"`,`data-rel="2"` e.t.c. not `data-rel="01"`, `data-rel="02"`.

Comment: thanks, it finally worked when i downloaded the jquerry.js file and had put into the root directory :)