# How to change pictures without leave the webpage in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a html page, in which I have several small button pictures array vertically on the left side, and a huge picture on the right side. When click the left side button pictures, the right side huge picture should change to something correspond with the button.

I know by use  I can show pictures in different areas. But I've no idea that how could I change the picture by clicking another picture. How to do it?

Comment: This should help you [Creating Content Tabs with Pure CSS](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/07/31/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/) also you can view my answer on similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886941/changing-content-on-the-same-html-file-page/22887278#22887278) but includes jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to change it now! By reviewing my own html code written months before, I've got the idea.

You can simply add a target attribute in <'a'> label to point to a iframe target!
Then you can click the picture or txt to change the content in iframe.

for example:

```
<a href="/html/pink.html" target="iframe">Pink World</a>
```

when click the "Pink World" text, you'll change the content of iframe into the content of pink.html under /html document.

Just that simple!

Comment: Yes but it's complicated, you must create an entire document for every picture. Use tabbed content instead, it's easier.

Comment: @mdesdev, thank you, I decided to learn javascript as my second programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do this by using events in the DOM of the pictures to change the page HTML so the images change.

Comment: Oh, I have only 3 hours left to complete this job, would that be sufficient to learn javascript? I totally have no experience about javascript. Just a few experience about python.

Comment: You don't need to learn *all* of JavaScript, just enough to do the bits you need.

Comment: @Zen I think you can also use just CSS BUT it may be much more complicated than just try getting started with `javascript`, which is very easy for a beginner (to solve your problem).

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to change huge in when click on button, here is two beginner tutorial for you, first for **click** event and second for **change image src**

[onClick Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)
[change img src](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp)

combine these two code to achieve your goal